# When running an Apache server, shouldn't people be able to enter my web page by using my IP?

Tags: php, apache

So I have MAMP up and running + index.php file in htdocs. Does that mean people can access my website by entering my IP when MAMP is working?

Comment: They can access your web server whenever there is an open route to it.

Comment: Unfortunately I just found out that apparently I have a dynamic IP address which allegedly means that I cannot host my website from the comfort of my home :( . Not that it's that big of a deal but I would've loved to have other people marvel at it.

Comment: In your sites-enabled directory you should have a default file that should point to your web directory. Anyone going to your IP address should get directed to the web directory specified here.

Comment: There are services such as www.noip.com that you can use to map to your dynamic address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is exactly right. Of course you will want to set your IP to a static IP so it doesn't get reset by your ISP. Or use a service like noip.com suggested by kojow7 for dynamic ips

Answer (score 0):

Similiar question

https://managewp.com/how-to-access-a-local-website-from-internet-with-port-forwarding

hope i helped you.